# Setting branch weight metadata in LLVM IR

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I'm trying to get my head around how metadata works in LLVM and how to set profiling metadata to specify branch weights, going by these docs for `BranchInst` specifically: https://llvm.org/docs/BranchWeightMetadata.html

Using the C API, my understanding of how metadata works leads me to believe this is how you would achieve this:

```c
LLVMMetadataRef branch_weights = LLVMMDStringInContext2(LLVMGetGlobalContext(), "branch_weights", 14);
LLVMMetadataRef weight1 = LLVMMDStringInContext2(LLVMGetGlobalContext(), "0", 1);
LLVMMetadataRef weight2 = LLVMMDStringInContext2(LLVMGetGlobalContext(), "100", 3);
LLVMMetadataRef mds[] = {branch_weights, weight1, weight2};
LLVMMetadataRef metadata = LLVMMDNodeInContext2(LLVMGetGlobalContext(), mds, 3);
LLVMValueRef metadata_value = LLVMMetadataAsValue(LLVMGetGlobalContext(), metadata);
```

But this gives the following in the IR:

```
!0 = !{!"branch_weights", !"0", !"100"}
```

When according to the docs linked above, I want this:

```
!0 = metadata !{
  metadata !"branch_weights",
  i32 <TRUE_BRANCH_WEIGHT>,
  i32 <FALSE_BRANCH_WEIGHT>
}
```

How can I achieve the above format in metadata, preferably with the C API, ensuring it's the `MD_prof` kind as mentioned in the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the main difference was having to use `LLVMValueAsMetadata` to get integers for the weights instead of strings, and then having to specify `prof` for the `kindID` field, giving:

```c
LLVMMetadataRef branch_weights = LLVMMDStringInContext2(LLVMGetGlobalContext(), branch, 14);
LLVMMetadataRef weight1 = LLVMValueAsMetadata(LLVMConstInt(LLVMIntType(32), 0, 0));
LLVMMetadataRef weight2 = LLVMValueAsMetadata(LLVMConstInt(LLVMIntType(32), 100, 0));
LLVMMetadataRef mds[] = {branch_weights, weight1, weight2};
LLVMMetadataRef metadata = LLVMMDNodeInContext2(LLVMGetGlobalContext(), mds, 3);
LLVMValueRef metadata_value = LLVMMetadataAsValue(LLVMGetGlobalContext(), metadata);

LLVMSetMetadata(<branch instruction here>, LLVMGetMDKindID("prof", 4), metadata_value);
```

This gives `!0 = !{!"branch_weights", i32 0, i32 100}` which though a slightly different format to what's in the docs still passes `opt -verify`, and should be parsed as an `MD_prof` node due to the `kindID` parameter.